# socket and fork with c

Tags: c, sockets, fork

Here a piece of my fork-server code:

```
    signal (SIGINT, ( void *)sig_handler);
while(1){
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));

    if((newsockd = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t *) &socket_len)) < 0){
        perror("Errore nella connessione\n");
        onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Ricevuta richiesta di connessione dall' indirizzo %s\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid < 0){
        perror("Fork error");
        onexit(newsockd, sockd, 0, 2);
    }
    if(child_pid == 0){
        do_child(newsockd);
    }
    else{
        attended_pid = waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
        if(attended_pid != child_pid){
            printf("Child error");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: have i to close the main sock (sockd) before executing the client?
I think no but:

- i've added a "sigint controller" and if i press CTRL-C on the server (with commented sockd -> `//close(sockd);`) the sigint will be executed 3 times with 2 concurrent connection (why??)
- if i have this code `close(sockd)` the sigint will be executed only 1 time but i got an `:bad file descriptor` on the `accept` instruction.

So, what have i to do?
Thanks!

PS: my sigint code:

```
void sig_handler(const int signo, const int sockd, const int newsockd){
  if (signo == SIGINT){
    printf("Ricevuto SIGINT, esco...\n");
    if(newsockd) close(newsockd);
    if(sockd) close(sockd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

Comment: off topic: `0` is a valid socket/file descriptor. So you should better initialize an unused socket/file descriptor to `-1` before usage and after having `close()`ed it and then use `-1` to test if it's a valid one or not.

Comment: In the parent process, you should call e.g. [`waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) at regular intervals to clean up after your children.

Comment: thanks :) i've re-updated my code but...what have i to "clean up" into the parent??

Comment: however the `multiple sigint` problem is still here :(

Comment: Why exactly are you calling `fork()` at all? All you do in the parent is block waiting for the child to exit? Why not just run the `do_child()` method inline?

Comment: i'm calling the `fork` because it is a ftp concurrent server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) manual page:

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

This tells me that you should *not* close the listening socket in the child process. You shouldn't close the accepted socket in the parent process either, but let it be closed by the child process when it's done.

Comment: So: 1) i have not to close sockd right? 2) i have to close newsockd into the child process so it is right to close child_sock, right?

Comment: @polslinux Yes to number 1. For nubmer 2, `newsockd` should be closed in the child, but what is `child_sock`?

Comment: `child_sock` is `newsockd` passed to the child! my function is `void do_child(const int child_sockd)` :)

Comment: @polslinux Ah okay, then you should close `child_sockd` in `do_child`.

Comment: i have updated the code, is now ok? :) PS: i have to add the waitpid...a second :D